# How to refund partial amount with adaptive paypal API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I just go through lots of the posts related this topic but can't found the solution. I just want to refund my partial amount to buyer. Like if buyer paid $50 for service and now want to refund, then buyer will get back with 2% deduction.

Bellow code is working fine with full amount refund, but I want partial amount.

Here is my code:

```
/* Refund API*/
$refundRequest = new RefundRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"));
//The receiver's email address, where n is between 0 and 5 for a maximum of 6 receivers
if(isset($_POST['receiverEmail'])) {
$receiver = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['receiverEmail']); $i++) {
    $receiver[$i] = new Receiver();
    $receiver[$i]->email = $_POST['receiverEmail'][$i];
    $receiver[$i]->amount = $_POST['receiverAmount'][$i];

    $receiver[$i]->primary = $_POST['primaryReceiver'][$i];
    if($_POST['invoiceId'][$i] != "") {
        $receiver[$i]->invoiceId = $_POST['invoiceId'][$i];
    }
    if($_POST['paymentType'][$i] != "" && $_POST['paymentType'][$i] != DEFAULT_SELECT) {
        $receiver[$i]->paymentType = $_POST['paymentType'][$i];
    }
    if($_POST['paymentSubType'][$i] != "") {
        $receiver[$i]->paymentSubType = $_POST['paymentSubType'][$i];
    }
    if($_POST['phoneCountry'][$i] != "" && $_POST['phoneNumber'][$i]) {
        $receiver[$i]->phone = new PhoneNumberType($_POST['phoneCountry'][$i], $_POST['phoneNumber'][$i]);
        if($_POST['phoneExtn'][$i] != "") {
            $receiver[$i]->phone->extension = $_POST['phoneExtn'][$i];
        }
    }
}
   $receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);
}
if($_POST['currencyCode'] != "") {
   $refundRequest->currencyCode = $_POST["currencyCode"];
}

if($_POST['payKey'] != "") {
   $refundRequest->payKey = $_POST["payKey"];
}

if($_POST['transactionId'] != "") {
   $refundRequest->transactionId = $_POST["transactionId"];
}

if($_POST['trackingId'] != "") {
   $refundRequest->trackingId = $_POST["trackingId"];
}

//Creating service wrapper object
$service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
try {
  /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
  $response = $service->Refund($refundRequest);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
   require_once 'Common/Error.php';
   exit;
}

$ack = strtoupper($response->responseEnvelope->ack);
if($ack != "SUCCESS"){
   echo 'error:';
} else { 
   $status = $response->refundInfoList->refundInfo[0]->refundStatus;
   print_r($response);
}
```

Can anyone let me know what's wrong in this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just got a solution myself:

here is edited code, simply added a receivers array in request:

```
$refundRequest->receiverList = $receiverList;
```

and you are done.

Hope this will help someone!